# ASP.NET Core 2.2 returns "NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size" on Many-to-Many insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, many-to-many

I got **"NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size"** when I try to insert into the linking table in **Many-to-Many** in **ASP.NET Core 2.2**.
I can insert values manually in SQL Server!

My entities are:

```
    public class Product
    {
        [key]
        public int Id {get;set;}

        public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();
    }
```

```
    public class Category
    {
        [key]
        public int Id {get;set;}

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();

    }
```

```
    public class ProductCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

in DbContext:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>().HasKey(t => new { t.ProductId, t.CategoryId });


            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Product)
                .WithMany(b => b.ProductCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ProductId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Category)
                .WithMany(c => c.ProductCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CategoryId);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories {get; set;}
```

I tries to insert records to Product and Category, The records inserted with no problem.
But as soon as I try to insert linking records I got **"NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size"** error.

Inserting :

```
            var Electronics = new Category
            {
                Name = "Electronics",
            };

            var Exir = new Product
            {
                Name = "Exir",
            };

            var pc1 = new ProductCategory();

            bc1.Product = Exir ;
            bc1.Category = Electronics;
            Exir.ProductCategories.Add(pc1);

            sqlContext.Categories.Add(Electronics);
            sqlContext.Products.Add(Exir);
            sqlContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I assume either `pc1` or `bc1` is a typo?

Answer (score 4):

This error can occur when a collection property is initialized with a fixed-size data structure, like an empty Array.

Answer (score 2):

As was stated above this type of error occurs when an ***extendable data structure*** is initialized with ***non-extendable data structure***.

In this case, by extendibility I mean whether the sequence has a finite (like an array) or flexible amount (Collection/List) of elements.

Example:

```
ICollection<string> collection = { "dummyValue" };
```

Have a look at the right side operator this is one of the ways of the array type initialization which is ***non-extendable data structure***.

---

Solution - to keep track of your assignment operators and argument types which are exposed to consumers.

P.S. The interesting thing about this is that it's not a compile-time error but the runtime error as the type matching, in this case, happens because of late binding.

Answer (score 1):

In our case the problem was that someone initialized the collection property with an `Array.Empty<T>`, assuming it would be replaced with a collection by EF.